# Passing integer lists to python

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I want to pass 2 lists of integers as input to a python program.

For e.g, (from command line)

```
python test.py --a 1 2 3 4 5 -b 1 2
```

The integers in this list can range from 1-50, List 2 is subset of List1.
Any help/suggestions ? Is `argparse` the right module ? Any concerns in using that ?

I have tried :

```
import argparse
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--a', help='Enter list 1 ')
    parser.add_argument('--b', help='Enter list 2 ')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print (args.a)
```

Comment: How does the list of integers look like?

Comment: Show a sample commandline you are going to use? Also, add common comments as part of the question.

Comment: integers in the each list range from 1 to 50. List 2 is subset of list1

Comment: Space-separated values are different arguments by convention. Either quote your lists (`"1 2 3 4 5"`) or comma-separate them (`1,2,3,4,5`) -- then `argparse` will treat them as one argument.

Comment: @katrielalex: `nargs="+"` changes this behaviour, so it eats `-a 1 2 3` as a single list

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pass them as strings than convert to lists. 
You can use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) or [optparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html).

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--l1', type=str)
parser.add_argument('--l2', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
l1_list = args.l1.split(',') # ['1','2','3','4']
```

Example: `python prog.py --l1=1,2,3,4`

Also,as a line you can pass something like this 1-50 and then split on '-' and construct range.
Something like this:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--l1', type=str, help="two numbers separated by a hyphen")
parser.add_argument('--l2', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
l1_list_range = xrange(*args.l1.split('-')) # xrange(1,50)
for i in l1_list_range:
    print i
```

Example: `python prog.py --l1=1-50`

Logic I think you can write yourself. :)

Comment: Any sample code to do that ? I also want to throw error if any list is empty or contains the number out of range ?

Comment: Please bring a sample list that you want to pass.

Comment: @Swati StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please make an attempt yourself at the problem and then ask for help with your solution.

Comment: sample list list1 contains number 1-50 and list2 contains subset of number from list1

Answer (score 84):

`argparse` supports [`nargs`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#nargs) parameter, which tells you how many parameters it eats.
When `nargs="+"` it accepts one or more parameters, so you can pass `-b 1 2 3 4` and it will be assigned as a list to `b` argument

```
# args.py
import argparse

p = argparse.ArgumentParser()

# accept two lists of arguments
# like -a 1 2 3 4 -b 1 2 3
p.add_argument('-a', nargs="+", type=int)
p.add_argument('-b', nargs="+", type=int)
args = p.parse_args()

# check if input is valid
set_a = set(args.a)
set_b = set(args.b)

# check if "a" is in proper range.
if len(set_a - set(range(1, 51))) > 0: # can use also min(a)>=1 and max(a)<=50
    raise Exception("set a not in range [1,50]")

# check if "b" is in "a"
if len(set_b - set_a) > 0:
    raise Exception("set b not entirely in set a")

# you could even skip len(...) and leave just operations on sets
# ...
```

So you can run:

```
$ python arg.py  -a 1 2 3 4 -b 2 20
Exception: set b not entirely in set a

$ python arg.py  -a 1 2 3 4 60 -b 2
Exception: set a not in range [1,50]
```

And this is valid:

```
$ python arg.py  -a 1 2 3 4 -b 2 3
```

Comment: good decision!
true if it is necessary to list the 50 numbers, not 5, it is long))

Comment: Because what you ask for *is* set checking. When you check if B is in A, *it is set operation* - check if set b - set a is empty. For ranges, I could use `min(a) >= 1 and max(a) <= 50`, although I wanted to be consistent. You asked about "List 2 is subset of List1.", no?

Comment: For validity checking, why not use `if all(1 <= a <= 50 for a in set_a)` ?

Comment: @InbarRose: nice one, if I refactored it, I would use it

Comment: How do I set a default list of values in this case?

Comment: @aviator you can set the default as a list, e.g. `default=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

`parser.add_argument('-i', '--ids', help="A comma separated list IDs", type=lambda x: x.split(','))`

**EDIT:**

I have just realised that this doesn't actually answer the question being asked. **Jakub** has the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

The way that [`optparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) and [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) work is they read arguments from the command line, arguments are split by white-space, so if you want to input your list of integers through the command line interfact from [`optparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) or [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) - you can do this by removing the spaces, or by surrounding your argument with `"`, example:

```
> my_script.py --a "1 2 3 4 5" --b "1 2"
```

or:

```
> my_script.py --a 1,2,3,4,5 --b  1,2
```

Your script then needs to convert these inputs into an actual list.

Using [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) syntax (very similar for [`optparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html)):

```
# with spaces and "
a_lst = [i for i in args.a.split(' ')] 
b_lst = [i for i in args.b.split(' ')]

# without spaces and ,
a_lst = [i for i in args.a.split(',')] 
b_lst = [i for i in args.b.split(',')]
```

---

Another way to do this would be by either importing the module you want to run and passing the list objects to a class that deals with your code, or by using a while loop and [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)/[`input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) to collect the desired list.

Answer (score 1):

If the *only* arguments are the lists and the separators, you can do it relatively simply:

```
sa = sys.argv.index('-a')
sb = sys.argv.index('-b')
lista = [int(i) for i in sys.argv[sa+1:sb]]
listb = [int(i) for i in sys.argv[sb+1:]]
```

Adding validation is easy:

```
aval = [i for i in lista if i>1 and i<50]
if len(aval) < len(lista):
    print 'The -a list contains invalid numbers.'
bval = [i for i in listb if i>1 and i<50]
if len(bval) < len(listb):
    print 'The -b list contains invalid numbers.'
```

Producing a help message:

```
if sys.argv[1] in ['-h', '-H'] or len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print "Usage: <name> -a [list of integers] -b [list of integers]"
```

Comment: I like your approach, how do I provide help regarding the input parameters and any validation about the range ?

Answer (score 1):

Just adding this one for completeness. I was surprised that I didn't see this approach.

```
from argparse import Action, ArgumentParser


class CommaSeparatedListAction(Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, values.split(','))


parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-l', action=CommaSeparatedListAction)
print(parser.parse_args('-l a,b,c,d'.split()))

# Namespace(l=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

This just a basic example, but you can also add validation or transform values in someway such as coercing them to uppercase.

```
from argparse import Action, ArgumentParser


class UppercaseLetterCommaSeparatedListAction(Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        letters = values.split(',')
        for l in letters:
            self._validate_letter(parser, l)
        setattr(
            namespace,
            self.dest,
            list(map(lambda v: v.upper(), letters))
        )

    def _validate_letter(self, parser, letter):
        if len(letter) > 1 or not letter.isalpha():
            parser.error('l must be a comma separated list of letters')


parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-l', action=UppercaseLetterCommaSeparatedListAction)
print(parser.parse_args('-l a,b,c,d'.split()))

# Namespace(l=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-l', action=UppercaseLetterCommaSeparatedListAction)
print(parser.parse_args('-l a,bb,c,d'.split()))

# usage: list.py [-h] [-l L]
# list.py: error: l must be a comma separated list of letters

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-l', action=UppercaseLetterCommaSeparatedListAction)
print(parser.parse_args('-l a,1,c,d'.split()))

# usage: list.py [-h] [-l L]
# list.py: error: l must be a comma separated list of letters
```